# 12.04 No Audio from HDMI After Switching Monitor Off / On

Tags: sound, hdmi

When booting Ubuntu 12.04, I have sound coming from my speakers through HDMI, except the start up sound (not a big deal). My card is listed in the sound settings. If I switch inputs on my monitor, the card (Radeon HD 5450) disappears.

I have tried both the proprietary drivers and open source drivers and nothing seems to fix it. As a side note my video settings don't stick after changing them. IE. Pixel format, GPU scaling, etc. I have this monitor connected with HDMI and also have a VGA cable connected to run a KVM switch, but 99% of the time run with the HDMI connection.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have the same problem too. Same hardware

Comment: Try `killall pulseaudio` (http://askubuntu.com/a/176276/45779)

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in terminal : alsamixer

and check if the master-sound is set to mute. (oo is unmute and mm is mute)

[image]

Comment: Master volume is set to 70. HDMI card still disappears when switching inputs on the monitor.