# HDMI sound disappears after suspend on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: suspend, pulseaudio, hdmi

My HDMI sound (Built-in audio) is gone after suspend. Does anyone know how to fix it?

I need to do `pulseaudio --kill; pulseaudio --start` every time after waking up from suspend, it's kinda annoying.

Comment: Have you checked other answers here [Ubuntu 16.04 changes sound device after suspend, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/a/767062/283843)

Answer (score 0):

It was happening in my New Omen X  Laptop

Finding a kernel mod in the link below solved this.  However it was more serious as my Sound Card was Not being shown at all.

But here is the fix in case it helps others just the same ...
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2401273&p=13801685#post13801685, 
Post #7

Comment: Nope Still Not working after Hibernation only after rebooting ... the patch described above is for NO HDA SOUND Nvidia Card recognised (Ubuntu's kernel has it TURNED OFF - FIX!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462670/set-default-profile-for-pulseaudio) very helpful.

To give you an example, in my case, I added the following line to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.1 output:hdmi-stereo
```