# Main sound device disappears after resuming from sleep mode

Tags: sound, suspend, 19.04

I have a problem with my sound since I upgraded to 19.04.

When I close my laptop, it goes to sleep. When I wake it up, it switches to "headphones".

Then, if I go to "sound device", my main speaker does not show. There's only the headphones that are here. I can't get my speakers back.

I have to reboot the computer to get my device back.

So, I formatted my laptop an reinstalled a clean 18.10, but the problem was still there.

I discovered [mr0's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034224/22949) to [Ubuntu changes sound device after suspend, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762816/ubuntu-changes-sound-device-after-suspend-how-to-fix), which says:

> Same happens for me but only if the HDMI monitor is not "awake" when OS starts or resumes: the list of devices in **Settings > Sound** doesn't even show **HMDI/DisplayPort - Built-in Audio** any more.
>
> The fix for me is to suspend the session, ensure HDMI monitor is on, resume the session.
>
> Suspend in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is somewhat insanely hidden behind the PowerOff button in the drop down menu: hold mouse down on it, or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to convert the PowerOff button into Suspend. Talk about hidden navigation!

So, I thought, "OK, I'll do that with 19.04", and I upgraded to 19.04.

But this solution does not work with the Disco Dingo release.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The following fixed the problem for me.

Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. Add:

```
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1
```

Reboot.

*Based on [Comment 3 for bug 1826868](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1826868/comments/3) by [Hui Wang](https://launchpad.net/%7Ehui.wang).*

Comment: Thank you for you advice.
I just have a little problem : I'm new to linux and the text editor tells me I don't have permission to edit this file. How can I get this permission ?

-- edit : OK, I've found there : https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-edit-as-root.html.en

Comment: It seems to work !
Thank you, you're my hero !